# How to get all records except the first 5 records after sorting based on a specific column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 18 records that are sorted based on specific column.

the first 5 records must be shown at first, and when click the specific button another records must be shown.

how can I do it ? I should use javascript?
it is my query...

```
public function theMostImportant()
{
    // return  CategoryActivity::all()->sortByDesc("priority")->take(5);
    return  CategoryActivity::all()->sortByDesc("priority");
}
```

in my view , my code is like this:

```
@foreach($priorityProjectCategory as $importantCategory)

    {{--{{dd($importantCategory)}}--}}

    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".{{str_replace(' ','',$importantCategory['faName'])}}"
        class="current">{{$importantCategory['faName']}}
        <sup></sup>
    </a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: There are lots of ways of implementing pagination, all widely discussed. Just pick whichever method works best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can consider the default pagination capability of Laravel. [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination)

or you can create a route like /categories?page=3 which takes page as an URL query, and perform;

```
$page = $request->query['page'];
$pageSize = 5;
$categories = CategoryActivity::all()->sortByDesc("priority")->offset($pageSize*($page-1))->limit($pageSize);
```

I recommend the pagintaion though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you basically need a show more functionality with pagination.

You can load first five records in first-time page load using ->take(5) and can show in your view blade file.

Then it will be good to use JS to asynchronously load the other records with ajax request on the button click.

In the ajax request you can set next records limit. And can skip first five using ->skip(5)

Answer (score 0):

to skip number of rows from result you can use `skip()` function along with `take()` function on 'Eloquent Query Builder. then call `get()` to get the result.

`skip(n)  // n = number of rows to be skipped`

`take(m)  // m = number of rows need to be take after the skip`

in this case 'm = number of all rows - n'

Possible solution

```
return  CategoryActivity::sortByDesc("priority")->skip(5)->take(
    CategoryActivity::sortByDesc("priority")->count() - 5
)->get();
```